# AngularJs 1 not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

im trying to fetch data from a json file but i doesnt work, i already check every options here but no one works for me, none of the code its working, i dont know if i have to import something else, and the json file its in the same level of the index file, hope you can help me

appClients.js

```
    (function(){
    var app = angular.module('customer',[]);
    alert('Success');
    app.controller("CustomerController",function($scope,$http){
        $http.get('../customer.json')
        .success(function(data) {
           // $scope.phones = data;
           alert('Success');
        })
        .error(function(data){
            alert('Error');
        });
    });
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="customer">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body class="Master" ng-controller="CustomerController as customer">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angularjs.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/appClients.js"></script>
        <header id="MasterHeader">

        </header>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="col-lg-6" id="CustomerList" ng-repeat="product in customer.clients">
                        <h3>{{product.id}}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6" id="CustomerDetails">Details</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer id="MasterFooter">

        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why using jQuery ?

Comment: Have a look at your dev tools. Do you get any errors in the console? Does that ajax call actually return anything or do you get a 404?

Comment: already check dev tools but didnt found a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your IIFE (Immediately-invoked function expression) is not being executed. Update your appClient.js file to

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('customer',[]);
    alert('Success');
    app.controller("CustomerController",function($scope,$http){
        $http.get('../customer.json')
        .success(function(data) {
           // $scope.phones = data;
           alert('Success');
        })
        .error(function(data){
            alert('Error');
        });
    });
})();
```

Note the additional `()` on the final line. This should allow you to see the initial "Success" alert.

If your ajax call then succeeds you would need to make the `$scope` property that the result is set to consistent with the `$scope` property referenced in the HTML. Based on the current snippet you seem to be setting the result to `$scope.phone` in the controller, but reference `$scope.customer` in your HTML.

Comment: now the angular code its working, thanks a lot but the ajax call return me error, what could it be?

Comment: What is your error message? You should be able to debug in dev tools (usually F12) or log the error to the console using `console.log(data)`. If this is a separate issue then it may be beneficial to create a separate question.